# Cannot target the element in Python - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, button, target

I am starting with Python - Selenium and I cannot target the element in login website. I tried many options of targeting this button but no options works (class name, css selector, id, name..). When I skip this step and get on the next page manually by exact url the finding, focusing, sending keys to element and clicking on the "Next" button is no problem but this "welcome" login button cannot target totally.
Using function "driver.find_element_by_XXX".

For example:
"driver.find_element_by_class_name("login-box-actions").click()"
Please, where I am making a mistake?

Many thanks,
regards David

```
<div class="login-box-actions">
                    <a style="cursor: pointer" ng-click="confirmLogin()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat ng-binding">Login</a>
                </div>
```

Comment: Try using XPATH. Open developer tools on your browser and try copying the element xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may fail because the element could not found. 
For that, you have to wait for the element to be load and clickable.

Refer to the following example, wait for the element to be clickable.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat ng-binding"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try finding the element by using different identifiers. Selenium supports:

find_element_by_id
find_element_by_name
find_element_by_xpath
find_element_by_link_text
find_element_by_partial_link_text
find_element_by_tag_name
find_element_by_class_name
find_element_by_css_selector

Answer (score 0):

You need to click into the `<a>` element instead of the div:

```
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Login']")
login_button.click()
```